# mac terminal (shell) loop

Tags: macos

I have a script that clicks the refresh button on firefox, and I have a script to delay. What I don't have is a script to make those actions repeat until I ^c it. How would I mkake this loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your script in a while loop.  Sample code below, in-depth tutorial [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_09_02.html).

```
#!/bin/bash

# This script opens 4 terminal windows.

i="0"

while [ $i -lt 4 ]
do
xterm &
i=$[$i+1]
done
```